# Is there a way to force mobs to constantly attack a player? (Minecraft 1.16.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So some mobs aren't constantly attacking players, such as vexes. Vexes only get angry every now and then. Evokers also don't constantly cast their magic, they wait a couple seconds between attacks. Is there a way to get these mobs to always be attacking the player?

No datapacks please.

Comment: Without datapacks, I don't see this being possible. This behaviour is built in to minecraft.